# Why doesn't this softlink work as expected?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fedora, sh

```
bash4.3 # pwd
/bin
bash4.3 # ll sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1   root    root    4   May 17 22:22 sh -> bash
bash4.3 # ll bash
-rwxr-xr-x. 1   root    root    1072056 May 17 22:22 bash
bash4.3 # bash
bash4.3 # sh
sh-4.3#
```

My OS is fedora 24 (Default GNOME version).

From the example, we can know: under `/bin`, `bash` is a binary executable; `sh` is a soft link to `bash`.

So, to my knowledge, `type bash and press enter` should effect the same result exactly as `type sh and press enter`.

When I `type bash and press enter`, I get `[root@localhost bin]#` as expected.

However, if I `type sh and press enter`, I surprisingly get `sh-4.3#`.

What's the cause?

Comment: Text which could quite easily be copy-pasted into a SE editor as an image is quite annoying, so please don't do this. Instead, select the text in your terminal and press CTRL-SHIFT-C.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is a documented feature.

If you run bash via a symlink named `sh`, bash will start in `sh` compatibility mode.

From `man bash`:

> If  bash  is  invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the
>   startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible,
>   while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.  When invoked as an
>   interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with  the  --login
>   option,  it  first  attempts  to  read and execute commands from
>   /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that order.  The --noprofile option
>   may be used to inhibit  this behavior.  When invoked as an interactive
>   shell with the name sh, bash looks for the variable ENV, expands its
>   value if  it  is  defined,   and  uses the expanded value as the name
>   of a file to read and execute.  Since a shell invoked as sh does not
>   attempt to read and execute commands from any other startup files, the
>   --rcfile option has no effect.  A non-interactive shell invoked with the name sh does not  attempt  to read any other startup files.  When
>   invoked as sh, bash enters posix mode after the startup files are
>   read.

#### How does a program know what name was used to start it?

If it is a c program, it can inspect `argv[0]`.  If it is a shell or perl script, it can inspect `$0`.

As an example, let's consider this simple shell script:

```
$ cat utc
#!/bin/sh
case "${0##*/}" in
        utc) date -u ;;
        et) TZ=US/Eastern date ;;
esac
```

`$0` is the name that the script was called by.  `${0##*/}` is the name that the script was called with any directory names removed.

Let's create this symlink:

```
ln -s utc et
```

So, `utc` and `et` both run the same executable but they provide different results.  When run as `utc`, it outputs universal time.  When run as `et`, is outputs US Eastern time.  For example:

```
$ utc
Wed Jul 20 18:14:18 UTC 2016
$ et
Wed Jul 20 14:14:20 EDT 2016
```

Comment: Might want to add how this is possible, since the OP expects the calls to be identical. (`argv[0]`, obvs)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good idea.  I added an example.

Comment: Perfect now. :)